# Two CSS declarations with same specificity have a strange behaviour

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

I have those two CSS declarations. Both have the same specificity - I even checked on a Specificity Calculator to be sure that they are equal. In that case the last declaration found in the CSS should be applied to the element, so the color of the list items should be green. For a reason that I cannot comprehend, in this case, they appear in red. Also quite inexplicably, the list bullets appear in green. Even if I had the "!important" rule to the "green" declaration it won't work.

```css
li:first-line { color: red; } 
ul li { color: green; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Go Out The House</li>
  <li>Get In Your Car</li>
  <li>Start Driving</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why it doesn't work is because you selecting the first line of the `li` which are each 1 line, hence they get applied to all.  If you switch the first-line to `ul` it will work as you expected.  The specificity is working as expected because of this.  Any additional lines in the `li` would be green.  That's why the bullets are green.

```css
ul:first-line { color: red; }
ul li { color: green; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Go Out The House</li>
  <li>Get In Your Car</li>
  <li>Start Driving</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Blog about `::first-line` https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-line/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul::first-line { color: red; } 
ul li { color: green; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li>Go Out The House</li>
  <li>Get In Your Car</li>
  <li>Start Driving</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that you applied the styling to the

element which is not correct because the

element doesn't have a first line as it is all only one line, thus you should apply to  element because it has multiple lines, thus is has a first line as a prat of it.
Hope that helped.